# Put request using Restlet + GWT

Tags: java, gwt, restlet

I have sucesfully tested cross domain GET requests in my app returning DomRepresentation the problem now is that it seems PUT operations are blocked as well as POST, I am getting 500 response.
I have added these headers:
    Series responseHeaders = (Series) getResponseAttributes().get(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS);

```
    if(responseHeaders == null){
        responseHeaders = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
        getResponseAttributes().put(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS, responseHeaders);
    }

    responseHeaders.add(new Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));
    responseHeaders.add(new Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"));
    responseHeaders.add(new Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"));
```

but no success can anybody confirm they have implemented this in GWT with Restlet 2.2 GWT release.

Do I have to set headers on the request also?

Comment: By default, GWT does not allow cross domain request, because it violates the SOP (Same Orign Policy).

Have you tried to run your app inside FireFox with a CORS-Plugin? Does this work?

Comment: So the GWT version of Restlet can only perform cross domain GET requests, I find this very strange, anybody involved with the Rest let library, please confirm this. Do you know if RestyGwt can do Posts, Puts?

Comment: Could you give us the stacktrace or reason that causes the 500 error?

Comment: Hi Jerome, I have reverted my code to do the calls server side. I was under the impression that if I needed to call Restlet from the client side, I would need to host my Restlet APP and the GWT app in the same domain?